# Pagination with LINQ on Stored Procedures?

Tags: linq, entity-framework, stored-procedures, pagedlist

Is there a way where I can use something like the following code to paginate data without loading the whole data-set to the program?

```
var r = from c in entities.GetSearchData(null,"en",null,true) select c;
IPagedList<Models.SearchResult> results = r.ToPagedList<Models.SearchResult>(1, 10);
```

I'm trying to use a stored procedure with LINQ to get a paged result. (BTW the above code gives a "The result of a query cannot be enumerated more than once." error). Is it possible?

Comment: For the error enumerated more than once: you may use r.ToList() to enumerate it more than once. You may also use Linq to fetch particular set of data using Take(), Skip() extension methods, by this way you may also omit use of stored procedure if you like.

Comment: But if I use ToList() data will get loaded before the pagination. I need to do it without loading the whole set.

Comment: Does your stored procedure accept paging parameters? Paging must be done internally by the stored procedure.

Comment: @Crypted: What I`m saying is var r = youstoredprocedure. Will load data to "r", but you can`t iterate over "r", so to do that you need to specify r.ToList(). I would suggest you to use pagination at stored-procedure check this, it might help you: http://sqlserverplanet.com/sql-server/best-sql-server-pagination-method

Answer (score 2):

Can't test with Entity Framework at the moment, but the regular LINQ-to-SQL allows following statements:

```
var rpage1 = entities.GetSearchData(null,"en",null,true).Skip(0).Take(10)
var rpage2 = entities.GetSearchData(null,"en",null,true).Skip(10).Take(10)
var rlist = rpage1.ToList();
```

LINQ will generate a clause like

```
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p0 + 1 AND @p0 + @p1
```

In my case the resulting query was (GetConstantsValues is a stored procedure):

```
SELECT [t1].[value] AS [Value]
FROM (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [t0].[value]) AS [ROW_NUMBER], [t0].[value]
    FROM [dbo].[GetConstantsValues](@p0) AS [t0]
    ) AS [t1]
WHERE [t1].[ROW_NUMBER] BETWEEN @p1 + 1 AND @p1 + @p2
ORDER BY [t1].[ROW_NUMBER]
```

So only the relevant results are loaded into program.

I reckon, EF shouldn't differ much from it. May be wrong.

Answer (score 1):

No need to go back to LINQ to SQL. There is a tweak that you can make. With entity framework, the result of a stored procedure is a collection of `ObjectSet`, hence the enumerations won't be allowed more than once, unless we convert it to a normal enumerable collection.

Simplest way to deal with such a case is as below,

```
var r = from c in entities.GetSearchData(null,"en",null,true) select c;
IPagedList<Models.SearchResult> results = 
    r.ToList().ToPagedList<Models.SearchResult>(1, 10);
```

Here r.ToList() makes the magic, and code would work without any hiccups!!

Note*: I know this is pretty old post, but thought of helping those who would come here looking for help!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! You don't need to include signature in your post - your user card is added automatically. Read [Help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/behavior) for more details.

Comment: Hint: to format text as a code - add four spaces before the line.